# Reputation graph in profile only shows parts of the account's existence

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-graph

Is it possible to see the reputation graph (line graph) for the entire existence of the account? Mine for example starts at 2500 reputation or so but I want to see it from zero if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find a full-scale interactive reputation graph on [your SE network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation):

[image]

This includes all your Stack Exchange accounts with a certain minimum reputation, not only Stack Overflow.